# I'm trying to insert textboxes values but it keeps showing ' syntax error near USER?

Tags: c#, web, sql-insert, executenonquery

```
protected void SubmitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename= C:\Users\HP\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\WebApplication2\WebApplication2\App_Data\eguidance.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");
        {

            SqlCommand sm = new SqlCommand( "Insert into USER ( email_address , first_name , last_name, ssn , password ) values ( @E_add, @f_name, @l_name ,@ssn , @pass )", con);
            sm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@E_add", E_add.Text);
            sm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f_name", f_name.Text);
            sm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@l_name", l_name.Text);
            sm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ssn", ssn.Text );
            sm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", pass.Text );

            con.Open();
            sm.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();


        }
```

Comment: Which database software are you using?  USER may be a reserved word.  If you are using Microsoft SQL, try putting [USER] instead.

Comment: do you running the code using a account that have Administrator privilage or not ?

Comment: @MostafizurRahman no I don't, thank you

Comment: @Aalia, you're welcome. I will post it as an answer then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

USER may be a reserved word. If you are using Microsoft SQL, try putting [USER] instead.